# Algorithm for generating heatmap in ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I want to build a heat map (a table like [this](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap)) for a ticketing system. I am receiving all ticket details from db data in JSON format. Below is an example. The actual data has 1000+ records.

```
{"ticketCount": 6, 
 "tickets": 
  [
    {"creationTimeMs": 1506061704724, 
     "expirationTimeMs": 1506083304724, 
     "queue": "low"}, 
    {"creationTimeMs": 1506127874782, 
     "expirationTimeMs": 1506149474782, 
     "queue": "low"}, 
    {"creationTimeMs": 1506283760321, 
     "expirationTimeMs": 1506283760322, 
     "queue": "high"}, 
    {"creationTimeMs": 1506236363281, 
     "expirationTimeMs": 1506257963281,  
     "queue": "high"}, 
    {"creationTimeMs": 1506283655948, 
     "expirationTimeMs": 1506283667938,  
     "queue": "low"}, 
    {"creationTimeMs": 1506283781894, 
     "expirationTimeMs": 1506284781894,  
     "queue": "medium"}
  ]
}
```

I would like a table with queue name (which is not fixed) as rows and time remaining (`currentTime - expirationTime`) as columns. I would like to have 5 columns with expiring in <10 mins, 10-30min, 30-1hr, 1-5hr,  >5hrs.

I know how to do in brute force by looping through json again and again. I wanted to know if we have some best algorithm and what ruby can offer to make it simple.

Comment: In Ruby this usually takes the form of `group_by` and some other stuff to crunch down the results into sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
require 'json'   

def cross_tab(json, range_mins)
  JSON.parse(json)["tickets"].each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |g,h|
    diff = g["etime"]-g["ctime"]
    h[[g["queue"], range_mins.rindex { |mn| mn <= diff }]] += 1
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
json = '{"ticketCount": 6, 
  "tickets": [
    {"ctime": 1506061704724, "etime": 1506083304724, "queue": "low"}, 
    {"ctime": 1506127874782, "etime": 1506149474782, "queue": "low"},
    {"ctime": 1506283760321, "etime": 1506283760322, "queue": "high"}, 
    {"ctime": 1506236363281, "etime": 1506257963281, "queue": "high"}, 
    {"ctime": 1506283655948, "etime": 1506283667938, "queue": "low"}, 
    {"ctime": 1506283781894, "etime": 1506284781894, "queue": "medium"}
  ]
}'

range_mins = [0, 10, 30, 60, 300].map { |n| 60000 * n }
  #=> [0, 600_000, 1_800_000, 3_600_000, 18_000_000]

h = cross_tab(json, range_mins)
  #=> {["low", 4]=>2, ["high", 0]=>1, ["high", 4]=>1, ["low", 0]=>1, ["medium", 1]=>1}

h[["high", 4]]
  #=> 1
h[["low", 3]]
  #=> 0
```

The second result obtains because `h` has a default value of `0` and no key `["low", 3]`.

We can now construct the contents of the crosstab (or *cross tabulation* or *contingency table*) as follows.

```
row_map = { 0=>"low", 1=>"medium", 2=>"high" }

tbl = Array.new(row_map.size) { |i|
        Array.new(range_mins.size) { |j| h[[row_map[i], j]] } }
  #=> [[1, 0, 0, 0, 2],
  #    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

The row (column) labels are obtained from `row_map` (`range_mins`)

We could alternatively compute `row_map` from `json`.

```
JSON.parse(json)["tickets"].map { |h| h["queue"] }.uniq.
  map.with_index { |queue, i| [i, queue] }.to_h
    #=> {0=>"low", 1=>"high", 2=>"medium"}
```

but this doesn't allow us to specify the order of the rows of the table or to produce a table with only some of the values of `"queue"`.

**Explanation**

The method uses the form of the class method [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument (here `0`) that is the *default* value for the hash. This simply means that if `h = Hash.new(0)` and `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` returns the default value. (The hash is not changed.)

A hash defined in this way is sometimes called a *counting hash*, commonly used (and is used that way here) with the calculation `h[k] +=1`. When Ruby sees this, the first thing she does is expand it to

```
h[k] = h[k] + 1
```

If `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` on the right of the equality (the method [Hash#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D)) is converted to the default value, `0`. Each subsequent time this expression is executed for the same key `k`, `h[k]` on the right returns the current value of `k` (i.e, the default value does not apply). (Note `h[k]` on the left of the equality is the method [Hash#[]=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D), which has nothing to do with the default value.)

The steps follow.

```
h = JSON.parse(json)
  #=> {"ticketCount"=>6,
  #    "tickets"=>[
  #      {"ctime"=>1506061704724, "etime"=>1506083304724, "queue"=>"low"},
  #      {"ctime"=>1506127874782, "etime"=>1506149474782, "queue"=>"low"},
  #      {"ctime"=>1506283760321, "etime"=>1506283760322, "queue"=>"high"},
  #      {"ctime"=>1506236363281, "etime"=>1506257963281, "queue"=>"high"},
  #      {"ctime"=>1506283655948, "etime"=>1506283667938, "queue"=>"low"},
  #      {"ctime"=>1506283781894, "etime"=>1506284781894, "queue"=>"medium"}
  #    ]
  #   }
a = h["tickets"]
  #=> [{"ctime"=>1506061704724, "etime"=>1506083304724, "queue"=>"low"},
  #    {"ctime"=>1506127874782, "etime"=>1506149474782, "queue"=>"low"},
  #    {"ctime"=>1506283760321, "etime"=>1506283760322, "queue"=>"high"},
  #    {"ctime"=>1506236363281, "etime"=>1506257963281, "queue"=>"high"},
  #    {"ctime"=>1506283655948, "etime"=>1506283667938, "queue"=>"low"},
  #    {"ctime"=>1506283781894, "etime"=>1506284781894, "queue"=>"medium"}]
e = a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0))
  #=> #<Enumerator: [
  #     {"ctime"=>1506061704724, "etime"=>1506083304724, "queue"=>"low"},
  #     {"ctime"=>1506127874782, "etime"=>1506149474782, "queue"=>"low"},
  #     ...
  #     {"ctime"=>1506283781894, "etime"=>1506284781894, "queue"=>"medium"}
  #   ]:each_with_object({})>
```

The first element element is generated by the enumerator, passed to the block, the block variables are set equal to that value and the block calculation is performed.

```
g, h = e.next
  # => [{"ctime"=>1506061704724, "etime"=>1506083304724, "queue"=>"low"}, {}]
g #=> {"ctime"=>1506061704724, "etime"=>1506083304724, "queue"=>"low"}
h #=> {}
f = g["queue"]
  #=> "low"
diff = g["etime"]-g["ctime"]
  #=> 1506083304724 - 1506061704724 => 21600000
j = range_mins.rindex { |mn| mn <= diff }
  #=> 4
```

This shows that `range_mins[4] #=> 18_000_000` is the largest value of `range_mins` that is less than or equal to `diff` (`21_600_000`)`. Continuing,

```
k = [f, j]
  #=> ["low", 4]
h[k] += 1
  #=> 1
h #=> {["low", 4]=>1}
```

The next value is then passed to the block by the enumerator `e`.

```
g, h = e.next
  #=> [{"ctime"=>1506127874782, "etime"=>1506149474782, "queue"=>"low"},
  #    {["low", 4]=>1}]
g #=> {"ctime"=>1506127874782, "etime"=>1506149474782, "queue"=>"low"}
h #=> {["low", 4]=>1}
f = g["queue"]
  #=> "low"
diff = g["etime"]-g["ctime"]
  #=> 1506149474782 - 1506127874782 => 21600000
j = range_mins.rindex { |mn| mn <= diff }
  #=> 4
k = [f, j]
  #=> ["low", 4]
h[k] += 1
  #=> 2
h #=> {["low", 4]=>2}
```

The remaining steps are similar.

Answer (score 0):

Successive applications of [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) can do this. Something like

```
data['tickets'].group_by { |ticket| ticket['queue'] }.transform_values do |tickets|
  tickets.group_by |ticket|
    # categorize ticket by time until expiry
  end
end
```

This results in a nested hash where the first level key is the queue name and the second level key is whatever categories you chose for the expiry time.